# Is it better to have a threadpool size = 1 or many threads being created, running a small task and terminating

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I don't work with threads very much. I have about 500 instances of a class using a synchronized block. I need to minimise the number of threads as much as possible.

Is it better to have a threadpool size = 1 or many threads being created, running a small task and terminating?

Comment: It depends on mainly things: Your requirements and your system configs. So there is no direct yes or no to this question.

Comment: If your only requirement is to minimize the number of threads, then why create any threads at all? What is driving you to want more than one thread?

Comment: P.S., Thread  pool always is better than continually creating and destroying short-lived threads. But `size==1` is a special case. You usually only see `size==1` when there is a requirement for tasks to run "in the background," but must be executed _sequentially_ "in the background."

Comment: I need to run the tasks in the background and only one component should use the synchronized block at a time so I think a threadpool size ==1 seems to be the better approach for my use case (and the block need not be synchronized). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. For CPU intensive tasks, you'll want to limit the number of threads to the number of CPU cores. For I/O intensive tasks, you can go higher, as many of those threads will be idle or waiting. Java offers a lot of configuration options, I'd start with reading about [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

You mentioned a `synchronized` block. If that covers most or all of your "async" task, there's not much point in having more than one thread. But note that if you have multiple instances of a class which has a `synchronized` *instance* method (so not a static method), those won't block each other.